# Whats the meaning of "she and Evan were about as fat as popsicle sticks " in this paragraph. Is it an idiom?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning, idioms-in-context

He'll pick up anything. The diet book, for instance that was just ridiculous. She and Evan were about as fat as popsicle sticks.

Comment: It's wordplay on an idiom. Normally one is said to be as skinny as a popsicle stick, or even just to *be* a popsicle stick. "Fat" is meant ironically.

Comment: Is the text in the body of your question a quotation? Please clarify and [cite your source](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1084/so-you-found-a-sentence-or-phrase-why-you-should-cite-your-source).

Comment: Please edit to add the source of this quote... You should paste a link to the source if you have one, if not then at least the title and author of the book you read it in.

Comment: This quote for example is from the New Yorker https://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2017/03/27/herman-melville-volume-i#:~:text=She%20and%20Evan%20were%20about%20as%20fat%20as%20Popsicle%20sticks.%20  But you may have read it somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

This is a joke. Since popsicle sticks are in fact very thin, the joke is that, despite considering themselves fat, they are not fat at all.